# AWS SAM Deploy error - Validation Error | CreateChangeSet Operation Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I get the following error upon attempting to `sam deploy --guided` my lambda application.

> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: {stack-name}, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:014009325916:stack/{stack-name}/f2212bf0-bb41-11ea-8ef3-0aa7af0536b6 is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and can not be updated.

Some further context into this issue is that all of my lambda functions do `not have authorization defined`. Not sure if that is related but I'm stating it in the case that it is.

I frankly have no idea how to go about this issue. Any help is appreciated.

===

**Context:**   Building an automated trading system

Request for Cloudformation Template:

`yaml`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: A tradingview alert wrapper that interprets alerts and makes trades according to them.

Globals:
    Function:
        # CodeUri: function/.
        # Runtime: python3.8
        # Policies:
        #     - AWSLambdaFullAccess
        # Tracing: Active
        # Timeout: 30
        Environment:
            Variables:
                APIKEY: ""
                SECRETKEY: ""


Resources:
    tradeFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            Handler: app.trade
            Description: The primary execution function
            CodeUri: function/.
            Runtime: python3.8
            Policies:
                - AWSLambdaFullAccess
            Tracing: Active
            Timeout: 60
            Events:
                inputResponse:
                    Type: Api
                    Auth:
                        ApiKeyRequired: false
                        Authorizer: NONE
                    Properties:
                        Path: /trade
                        Method: post
                        

    printAccountBalanceFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: function/.
            Runtime: python3.8
            Policies:
                - AWSLambdaFullAccess
            Tracing: Active
            Timeout: 30
            Handler: app.print_account_balance
            Description: Returns account balance over time or trade
            Events:
                inputResponse:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /print_account_balance
                        Method: get
    startTradesFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: function/.
            Runtime: python3.8
            Policies:
                - AWSLambdaFullAccess
            Tracing: Active
            Timeout: 30
            Handler: app.start_trades
            Description: Resets trade log for a fresh start
            Events:
                inputResponse:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /start_trades
                        Method: get                   
    retrieveTradeLogFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: function/.
            Runtime: python3.8
            Policies:
                - AWSLambdaFullAccess
            Tracing: Active
            Timeout: 30
            Handler: app.retrieve_trade_log
            Description: Return all the trade logs in the dyanamoDB database
            Events:
                inputResponse:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /retrieve_trade_log
                        Method: get
```

Comment: Can you paste your `cloudformation` template here?

Comment: added the template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932734/validationerror-stackarn-aws-cloudformation-stack-is-in-rollback-complete-state 

This seems to be similar issue?

Comment: yes it is very similar. I used the information on that issue and got the solution. thanks @dinakaran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is encountered to my understanding when one does an initial deployment and that initial deployment fails. As a result of this, something breaks and the deployment service can not execute successfully. To fix this issue, simple delete the `aws cloudformation stack` and redeploy.

One can use the following command to delete:

`aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name <insert stack-name>`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932734/validationerror-stackarn-aws-cloudformation-stack-is-in-rollback-complete-state)

Comment: bro you're a legit life saver

Answer (score 0):

Might need to run `sam build` first so your resources can get the latest changes